# Issue in curl command using RestComm

Tags: curl, jboss, sip, restcomm, mobicents

http://www.telestax.com/restcomm-sip-tutorial-basic-usage-and-voice-dtmf/

by refering this site i am going to Test RestComm with a Sip Phone, but facing much issue in curl command which is given below

curl –-data “PhoneNumber=1234&VoiceUrl=http://127.0.0.1:8080/restcomm/demo/hello-world.xml&VoiceMethod=POST” http://ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf:77f8c12cc7b8f8423e5c38b035249166@127.0.0.1:8080/restcomm/2012-04-24/Accounts/ACae6e420f425248d6a26948c17a9e2acf/IncomingPhoneNumbers.json

while running this i am getting

JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final - JBWEB000064: Error report

## JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 401 -

**JBWEB000309: type** JBWEB000067: Status
 report

**JBWEB000068: message**

**JBWEB000069: description** JBWEB000121: This request requires HTTP authentication.

#### JBoss Web/7.2.0.Final

i spent much time to resolve but i did'nt please help to resolve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Sorry that you are experiencing problems using Curl with Restcomm. Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve with the above command?

Which version of Restcomm are you using?

I suggest you use the Restcomm quick user guide as explained here : http://docs.telestax.com/restcomm-quick-start-user-guide/

Regards

TechKid

Comment: I am using latest Restcomm-JBoss-AS7-7.6.0.825